# Could anyone explain the logs from my IPMI

Tags: logging, ipmi

my server is suffering freezing these days. I thought it was software problem. Then I found something strange from server log

```
113,System Event,02/12/2014 11:16:50 Wed,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
114,System Event,02/12/2014 16:20:16 Wed,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
115,System Event,02/13/2014 08:43:53 Thu,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
116,System Event,02/13/2014 12:49:30 Thu,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
117,System Event,02/13/2014 15:13:00 Thu,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
118,System Event,02/13/2014 19:31:23 Thu,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
119,System Event,02/13/2014 19:44:51 Thu,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
120,System Event,02/13/2014 21:47:37 Thu,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
121,System Event,02/14/2014 03:04:36 Fri,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Uncorrectable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
122,System Event,02/14/2014 08:05:25 Fri,Memory,,Assertion: Memory| Event = Correctable ECC@DIMM?6(CPU1)
```

Could any one explain what is that mean. Is there any wrong server configure or bad memory stick? My board have only 4 slots each CPU, where is the bad memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. DIMM #6 is bad. Get it out of there.

Comment: Which slot it could be? There is only 4 slots for each CPU

Comment: Best guess is that it's the 3rd stick on the 2nd CPU. You'd have to consult the motherboard's manual or manufacturer support for more details to be sure.

Comment: DIMM is a memory stick, not a CPU.  The slots are usually numbered 0 to N.  Your manual or the motherboard should tell you which one is slot 6.

Comment: Check documentation. Absent documentation, you can figure this out by a process of elimination. Does your server tell you what memory you have in which slots when it POSTs, or when you go into the BIOS setup program? If you remove some memory, which slots are then shown as empty? Basic critical thinking is all that is required here. But, if you go down this road, be sure not to lose track of which module was which.

Comment: @metatflag What is the `(CPU1)` for?